# Blazor Checkbox Group Two-Way Binding

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

I'm a newbie with Blazor and have not been able to perform a two-way binding using a group of checkboxes, no matter if I check or uncheck the checkboxes within the child component, the count is not reflected in the parent.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

Child Component

```
<div class="btn-group">
    @foreach(Item item in Items)
    {
        <input id="chk_@item.Id" type="checkbox" class="btn-check" @bind="item.Selected">
        <label for="chk_@item.Id" class="btn btn-success">@item.Name</label>
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new();
}
```

Parent Component

```
<Child Items="items"></Child>
<p>@items.Where(n => n.Selected).Count() Items Selected</p>

@code {
    private List<Item> items = new()
    {
        new Item { Name = "Foo" },
        new Item { Name = "Bar" }  
    };
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work quite like classic Bootstrap.

You need to change the elements around a little.

```cs
<div class="btn-group" >
    @foreach (Item item in Items)
    {
        <button class="btn @(item.Selected ? "btn-primary": "btn-outline-primary")" @onclick="() => SetCheck(item)">@item.Name</button>
    }
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new();
    [Parameter] public EventCallback ItemsChanged { get; set; }

    private async Task SetCheck(Item item)
    {
        item.Selected = !item.Selected;
        await ItemsChanged.InvokeAsync();
    }
}
```

And **Index**

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<Child Items="items" ItemsChanged=this.OnItemsChanged></Child>

<div class="bg-dark text-white mt-3 p-2">
    <pre>@items.Where(n => n.Selected).Count() Items Selected</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private List<Item> items = new()
    {
        new Item { Name = "Foo" },
        new Item { Name = "Bar" }
    };
     
    //Don't need to do anything.
    // Will trigger a UI update by it's presence
    private Task OnItemsChanged()
        => Task.CompletedTask;
    
}
```